# Navigation Item Title not Showing

Tags: ios, swift

I have following code in `class homeVC: UICollectionViewController` to display the title in the navigation bar and it works as expected.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    .
    .
    .
    self.navigationItem.title = PFUser.current()?.username?.uppercased()
    .
    .        
}
```

But when I clicked on the button to go to another view controller and then came back to homeVC view controller `self.navigationItem.title` is not displaying anything. I'mm wondering why that happened?

The following code is to go to another view controller

```
@objc func followersTap() {

    category = "followers"

    // make references to followersVC
    let followers = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "followersVC") as! followersVC

    // present
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(followers, animated: true)
}
```

This is the view controller to go to , and in this view controller i don't want to show the title from previous view controller so I'm using `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = ""`  to make it empty and when I go back to previous view controller the title is also empty, why?

```
class followersVC: UITableViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = ""  

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I am trying to not show the first view controller title on second view controller top left corner where back button is and keep first and second view controller title shows.

Comment: No, i reset the second view controllers title not first one

Comment: I am trying to remove the first view controller title from second view controller back icon on the top left corner. But when i do that it remove all first view controller titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your plan is to not show the title from a previous view controller, the solution is like this:

Change:

```
self.navigationItem.title = PFUser.current()?.username?.uppercased()
```

to:

```
self.title = PFUser.current()?.username?.uppercased()
```

And change:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = ""
```

to:

```
self.title = ""
```

Comment: By doing this it i can see first view controller title without any issue but it didn't remove first view controller title from second view controller at left corner where back button is. also remove the second view controller title.

Comment: let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil) self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton, add this lines under title to first VC, @Alvin123

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. Now its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `self.navigationItem.title = PFUser.current()?.username?.uppercased()` in `viewDidAppear()`, this should help

Comment: Now it remove the second view controller title not first one. I am trying to remove the first view controller title from second view controller back icon on the top left corner. But when i do that it remove all first view controller titles.